# Laravel - PrettyPageExceptions not working

Tags: php, laravel

Everything was working fine until yesterday.
Exceptions were thrown in cool laravel orange/black style format.

But now, I just see a blank page and exceptions are not visible.
When I inspect the call, it shows 500 Internal Server Error.

Here is the stack trace from laravel logs:

```
   [2014-09-16 20:07:32] local.ERROR: exception 'Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException' in E:\xampp\htdocs\ingeniouslive\app\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\RouteCollection.php:148
Stack trace:
#0 E:\xampp\htdocs\ingeniouslive\app\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Router.php(1049): Illuminate\Routing\RouteCollection->match(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#1 E:\xampp\htdocs\ingeniouslive\app\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Router.php(1017): Illuminate\Routing\Router->findRoute(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#2 E:\xampp\htdocs\ingeniouslive\app\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Router.php(996): Illuminate\Routing\Router->dispatchToRoute(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#3 E:\xampp\htdocs\ingeniouslive\app\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Application.php(777): Illuminate\Routing\Router->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#4 E:\xampp\htdocs\ingeniouslive\app\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Application.php(747): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#5 E:\xampp\htdocs\ingeniouslive\app\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Session\Middleware.php(72): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), 1, true)
#6 E:\xampp\htdocs\ingeniouslive\app\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Cookie\Queue.php(47): Illuminate\Session\Middleware->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), 1, true)
#7 E:\xampp\htdocs\ingeniouslive\app\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Cookie\Guard.php(51): Illuminate\Cookie\Queue->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), 1, true)
#8 E:\xampp\htdocs\ingeniouslive\app\vendor\stack\builder\src\Stack\StackedHttpKernel.php(23): Illuminate\Cookie\Guard->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), 1, true)
#9 E:\xampp\htdocs\ingeniouslive\app\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Application.php(643): Stack\StackedHttpKernel->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#10 E:\xampp\htdocs\ingeniouslive\app\repo\index.php(49): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->run()
#11 {main} [] []
[2014-09-16 20:07:32] local.ERROR: exception 'RuntimeException' with message 'Could not find resource 'views/layouts.html.php' in any resource paths.(searched: E:\xampp\htdocs\ingeniouslive\app\vendor\filp\whoops\src\Whoops\Handler/../Resources)' in E:\xampp\htdocs\ingeniouslive\app\vendor\filp\whoops\src\Whoops\Handler\PrettyPageHandler.php:440
Stack trace:
#0 E:\xampp\htdocs\ingeniouslive\app\vendor\filp\whoops\src\Whoops\Handler\PrettyPageHandler.php(119): Whoops\Handler\PrettyPageHandler->getResource('views/layouts.h...')
#1 E:\xampp\htdocs\ingeniouslive\app\vendor\filp\whoops\src\Whoops\Run.php(247): Whoops\Handler\PrettyPageHandler->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException))
#2 E:\xampp\htdocs\ingeniouslive\app\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Exception\WhoopsDisplayer.php(49): Whoops\Run->handleException(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException))
#3 E:\xampp\htdocs\ingeniouslive\app\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Exception\Handler.php(280): Illuminate\Exception\WhoopsDisplayer->display(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException))
#4 E:\xampp\htdocs\ingeniouslive\app\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Exception\Handler.php(159): Illuminate\Exception\Handler->displayException(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException))
#5 E:\xampp\htdocs\ingeniouslive\app\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Application.php(753): Illuminate\Exception\Handler->handleException(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException))
#6 E:\xampp\htdocs\ingeniouslive\app\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Session\Middleware.php(72): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), 1, true)
#7 E:\xampp\htdocs\ingeniouslive\app\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Cookie\Queue.php(47): Illuminate\Session\Middleware->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), 1, true)
#8 E:\xampp\htdocs\ingeniouslive\app\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Cookie\Guard.php(51): Illuminate\Cookie\Queue->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), 1, true)
#9 E:\xampp\htdocs\ingeniouslive\app\vendor\stack\builder\src\Stack\StackedHttpKernel.php(23): Illuminate\Cookie\Guard->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), 1, true)
#10 E:\xampp\htdocs\ingeniouslive\app\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Application.php(643): Stack\StackedHttpKernel->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#11 E:\xampp\htdocs\ingeniouslive\app\repo\index.php(49): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->run()
#12 {main} [] []
[2014-09-16 20:07:32] local.ERROR: exception 'Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException' with message 'Uncaught exception 'RuntimeException' with message 'Could not find resource 'views/layouts.html.php' in any resource paths.(searched: E:\xampp\htdocs\ingeniouslive\app\vendor\filp\whoops\src\Whoops\Handler/../Resources)' in E:\xampp\htdocs\ingeniouslive\app\vendor\filp\whoops\src\Whoops\Handler\PrettyPageHandler.php:440
Stack trace:
#0 E:\xampp\htdocs\ingeniouslive\app\vendor\filp\whoops\src\Whoops\Handler\PrettyPageHandler.php(119): Whoops\Handler\PrettyPageHandler->getResource('views/layouts.h...')
#1 E:\xampp\htdocs\ingeniouslive\app\vendor\filp\whoops\src\Whoops\Run.php(247): Whoops\Handler\PrettyPageHandler->handle(Object(RuntimeException))
#2 E:\xampp\htdocs\ingeniouslive\app\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Exception\WhoopsDisplayer.php(49): Whoops\Run->handleException(Object(RuntimeException))
#3 E:\xampp\htdocs\ingeniouslive\app\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Exception\Handler.php(280): Illuminate\Exception\WhoopsDisplayer->display(Object(RuntimeException))
#4 E:\xampp\htdocs\ingeniou' in E:\xampp\htdocs\ingeniouslive\app\vendor\filp\whoops\src\Whoops\Handler\PrettyPageHandler.php:440
Stack trace:
#0 [internal function]: Illuminate\Exception\Handler->handleShutdown()
#1 {main} [] []
```

I can see something going wrong on #4. Only a partial directory path is listed: `E:\xampp\htdocs\ingeniou'`

I am not sure how to debug this. Please help.

PS: Things stopped working when I setup email(edited app/config/mail.php) and ran couple of artisan commands(auth:reminder-controller and auth:reminder-table)

Comment: Try `php artisan clear-compiled`.

Comment: Nope. Nothing. Issue persists.

Comment: Is there an exception message with the stack trace?

Comment: I updated the stack trace. Appropriate exception is thrown in log file.

Comment: Okay guys the error vanished after reinstalling Laravel. I wonder what the issue was.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue as well and had to do a fresh install of Laravel to get it working.  I THINK it was caused when I refactored a folder in my views from layout to layouts.  It may have done some extra refactoring and switched things up where they shouldn't' have been in other classes?

Might be best to just do a new install of laravel.